# VLC plugin to keep track how many times I watched a video

Tags: gratis, windows-7, vlc

I am looking for a free [VLC plugin](http://addons.videolan.org/) that keeps track of how many times I played a video.

Ideally:

- can import/export data
- record what percentage of the video I watched as well as what part (e.g. second 30  to second 180)
- works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate

Comment: If anyone has any idea

Comment: please add an answer.